# вывод сообщения в тестах на C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Какой метод еще принимает текстовую строку сообщения при успешном тестировании и возвращает ее?

Comment: Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual,"Подключение НЕ создано");

Comment: Библиотек для юнит-тестирования существует несколько штук. Какую именно вы используете?